# Why is howler not playing?

Tags: node.js, audio, howler.js

I am trying to run a webscraper(with node and puppeteer) and when needed it will alert me with a sound. I found howler, but when I use it it doesn't make any sound.

```
    import {Howl, Howler} from 'howler';

    var sound = new Howl({
        src: ['soundEffect.mp3']
    });
    
    sound.play();
```

Comment: Any debugging messages?  Check your pathing, perhaps try './soundEffect.mp3'

Comment: There are no messages, and I tried the ./.